# Why my var is null and the code doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, events

I'm starting with the basics in JS and I try to make my first event, change the image if it clicked but it's not working, where's the prob?

```
let myImage = document.querySelector('img');

myImage.onclick = function() {
    let mySrc = myImage.getAttribute('src');
    if(mySrc === 'images/coding_icon.png') {
      myImage.setAttribute ('src','images/coding2.png');
    } else {
      myImage.setAttribute ('src','images/coding_icon.png');
    }
}
```

My var myImage return NULL and nothing happen when I click on my image. It seems that the doc...selector don't select the first occur of img. Sorry if I did something wrong with the post, it's my first time posting here.
Thanks

Comment: The most common cause of that is code (the code you posted) placed *before* the body of the HTML document. If you move the `<script>` to the end of the `<body>` that would solve that particular problem.

Comment: No way!!! It works!!! Thanks man or girl, whatever, you saved me from getting mad! Thanks!!!

Comment: @Shinjuo you don't need the attributes here better use the properties: `myImage.onclick = function() { myImage.src = myImage.src === 'images/coding_icon.png' ? 'images/coding2.png': 'images/coding_icon.png'; }`

Answer (score 2):

You are probably using querySelector on img before it really loaded into DOM.

Possible solutions:

1) move your script in the body tag after the img tag declaration.

2) use code on event of other tags, for e.g. on a button click

3) you can put a timeout surrounding script so that it run delayed and DOM can be loaded meanwhile

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with point 2. But point 3 is a no-go in my opinion. It may work, but no. Just no.